# How to examine if a the time of a DateTime is between 9 PM and 17 PM (Ruby)?

Tags: ruby, datetime, integer

I have this datetime:

```
time = 2013-08-21 11:54:49 +0200
```

I also have two integers that represents a time interval. For example if I wish it to be between 9 AM and 5 PM I will use:

```
start  = 9
finish = 17
```

I now wish to examine if the datetime is within the interval of the two integers. In this example the result would be `true`, because the event at 11:54 is between 9 and 17...

How to do this?

Comment: Firstly the event assignment is not correct and this will cause you some trouble.  That would need to be fixed so that the code can actually run.

Comment: You could assign (now instead of event, it is time) like this: time = Time.new(2013, 8, 21, 11, 54, 49, "+02:00") Or use DateTime.parse to use a string.  Your assignment simply will not work as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about timezones the code could look something like:

`(start..finish).include? DateTime.now.strftime('%H').to_i`

Answer (score 1):

In your question the assignment is not correct. This would work:

```
require 'date'
event = DateTime.parse('2013-08-21 11:54:49 +0200')
```

If you have a `DateTime` instance you can simply use `#hour`:

```
event.hour # => 11
```

You can compare this integer with any other:

```
event.hour.between?(start, finish) # => true
```